# Delete a reply to a comment in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

How can I delete a reply to a comment in Microsoft Word 2013?

[image]

I use Microsoft Word 2013 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this matches your version, but what I did was open the "Reviewing Pane" - This showed a history of all comments, including the addition of the blank comment.

From there, you can right click and delete the extra comment.

Comment: What a PITA. Worked for me.